# Firefox: "an unexpected error has occurred". OK, what next?

Tags: macos, firefox, error-logging

For the last week or two, I've been getting this little temporary pop up dialog with an audio jingle to the right hand top of my Firefox window.  "An unexpected error has occurred".  Flame icon, no explanatory text.  Then it disappears.  And nothing really much happens.

No idea of what wrong where, and in what tab.

OK, I can give you the OS version:  Sierra and the FF, 64.0.2 (stable as of right now).  **But what I'd like to know is:  does Firefox keep a log somewhere of these event?**  Or is it just pointless nagging?

I've seen a bunch of references to this error, but everyone else pretty much already knows the context of their errors.  I don't.

Checked the OS system log and, while I see other Firefox events, nothing that matches the timing, so the errors aren't being reported there.

#### enabled extensions, none of which have been added recently:

- Adblock Plus
- Cookie AutoDelete
- NoScript
- Pinboard Bookmark
- Web Developer

Comment: gotta love to **close votes** with no reason given ;-)  I assume it's not macos specific, which is why it's here rather than Ask Different.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the pop-up dialog (to identify if it's possibly browser, extension or OS related)? First I would confirm extensions are not involved by checking for the error with extension(s) disabled. Beyond that, you might run Browser Console in a side window and see what is happening when the error pops up.

Comment: OK, so it ends up being `Cookie Autodelete`.  And, I get that the dev may just do the equivalent of an `alert("error")`.  But, does FF provide any support in its notification mechanism that at least says which extension pushed them out?  I have very few extensions so it wasn't too difficult to narrow it down.  But what if I had 20-30?